# Logging RotatingFileHandler not rotating

Tags: python-3.x, logging

I have implemented a custom RotatingFileHandler:

```
class FreezeAwareFileHandler(RotatingFileHandler):
    def emit(self, record):
        try:
            msg = self.format(record)
            stream = self.stream
            stream.write(msg)
            stream.write('\n')
            self.flush()
        except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit): #pragma: no cover
            raise
        except:
            self.handleError(record)
```

And I have this configuration json file (I have tried even with yaml and specifying the configuration through the class methods):

```
{
  "version": 1,
  "disable_existing_loggers": false,

  "formatters": {
    "standard": {
      "format": "%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s",
      "datefmt": "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
    }
  },

  "handlers": {
    "freeze_aware_file_handler": {
      "class": "Logging.MyHandler",
      "formatter": "standard",
      "level": "INFO",
      "filename": "logs\\MyLog.log",
      "maxBytes": 1024,
      "backupCount": 10,
      "encoding": "utf8"
    }
  },

  "loggers": {
    "my_module": {
      "level": "INFO",
      "handlers": ["my_handler"],
      "propagate": "no"
    }
  },

  "root": {
    "level": "INFO",
    "handlers": ["my_handler"]
  }
}
```

And this is the code I use for initializing:

```
if os.path.exists(path):
        with open(path, 'rt') as f:
            config_json = json.load(f)       
        logging.config.dictConfig(config_json)

    logger = logging.getLogger("my_handler")
```

I can normally log to the specified file but it is never rotating.
Someone know why I'm having this behavior?
I'm using Python 3.5

Answer (score 0):

It turned out the problem was really simple.
For the rotating file handler it is needed to explicitly call the shouldRollver and doRollover methods in the emit of the base class.

```
def emit(self, record):
        try:
            if self.shouldRollover(record):
                self.doRollover()

            ...
            do any custom actions here
            ...

        except:
            self.handleError(record)
```